# How to restrict access by IP address with Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver

Does anyone know if Tomcat can restrict access to certain application by IP address (like Apache's `.htaccess`)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You add a `Valve` to the `Context` in `context.xml` (specifically, `org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve`). See the docs on [Remote Host Filters](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter).

Answer (score 26):

**This is an example:**

In `apache-tomcat-7.0.33\conf\server.xml`:

```xml
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    ...
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
           allow="10\.132\.77\.55|10\.132\.76\.120|10\.132\.77\.47"/>
    ...
</Engine>
```

Comment: the config file can be in these directories also '/etc/tomcat8/server.xml' '

Comment: this can be also used in securing manager and host-manager access.

Answer (score 5):

In Tomcat 7, you can configure it in the `web.xml`.

If it's for all web apps, you can configure it in `tomcat7/conf/web.xml`, if it is just for one web app, you can configure it in the `tomcat7/webapps/$(WEB_APP)/WEB-INF/web.xml`, it's very convenient.

The configuration uses a `RemoteAddrFilter` filter, there is an example in [Container Provided Filters](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter).

Answer (score 2):

To set up access restriction to your web-application for the certain IP addresses, add the following strings to ***/opt/tomcat/webapps/{web-application name}/META-INF/context.xml*** file:

```xml
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" deny="{IP_address}" />
</Context>
```

Here is the [instruction how to do this](https://jelastic.com/blog/restrict-access-tomcat-web-application-hosting/) via Jelastic panel. Be sure to restart your Tomcat for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking how to restrict access for just a single webapp. By replacing "ROOT" by that specific webapp, it worked. Thanks for pointing to the great source!

Comment: Oh by the way (for everyone trying this method), you have to restart your Tomcat instance for the IP restriction to take effect. Futhermore, you can replace `deny` by `allow` to only allow certain IP's rather than only blocking certain IP's.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For 8.5.37, only this solution works. Unfortunately, all other solutions are missing the RemoteIpValve statement.

Answer (score 0):

in Tomcat 9,you can configure it in path:`apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml`