# Tomcat: Restrict access to localhost for /just one/ webapp

Tags: security, tomcat, webserver, tomcat6

I'm running Tomcat 6 to serve several web apps, most of which are public-facing.  But I'd like to restrict access to *just one* webapp, allowing connections only from localhost.

I can restrict access for *all* webapps using a valve in context.xml, as described in:

- [Tomcat Restrict access by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381531/tomcat-restrict-access-by-ip-address)

But I can't figure out how to restrict access on a per-app basis.  Is there a way to do this with my app's web.xml?  Or by adding additional rules to context.xml?

Thanks,

-B

---

## Recapping Solution:

```
$ cp /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/context.xml \ 
   /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/my-app-name.xml

$ cat /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/my-app-name.xml

<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve" allow="localhost"/>
... {as previously} ...
</Context>
```

Comment: A Context IS a "single app". Each WAR is it's own context. What definition of app are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an individual context.xml for you app.

This is an excerpt from Tomcat doc on context configuraion:
Context elements may be explicitly defined:

- In the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml` file: the Context element information will be loaded by all webapps.
  In the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default` file: the Context element information will be loaded by all webapps of that host.
- In individual files (with a `.xml` extension) in the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` directory. The name of the file (less the `.xml`) extension will be used as the context path. Multi-level context paths may be defined using `#`, e.g. `foo#bar.xml` for a context path of `/foo/bar`. The default web application may be defined by using a file called `ROOT.xml`.
- Only if a context file does not exist for the application in the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/`; in an individual file at `/META-INF/context.xml` inside the application files. If the web application is packaged as a WAR then `/META-INF/context.xml` will be copied to `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` and renamed to match the application's context path. Once this file exists, it will not be replaced if a new WAR with a newer `/META-INF/context.xml` is placed in the host's appBase.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing `localhost` didn't work for me. I use `RemoteAddrValve` instead. Keep in mind that some systems use IPv4 addresses (your filter has to match match `127.0.0.1`) while others use IPv6 addresses (match the full address, not abbreviated notations like `::1`).

```
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
           allow="0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,127\.0\.0\.1" />
</Context>
```

The attribute `allow` takes a regexp, so dots need to be escaped. As [explained by Dmitry Negoda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5224266/897024), this goes in `/META-INF/context.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Goto following path:  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\

Under this path you find " manager.xml " file.

Edit " manager.xml " file,with following content:

```
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" 
   allow="127.0.0.1,10.100.1.2"/>

  <!-- Link to the user database we will get roles from
  <ResourceLink name="users" global="UserDatabase" 
    type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  -->
```

********** save and run server....You got it.
NOTE : 127.0.0.1 MEANS YOUR SYSTEM IP
       10.100.1.2 -THIS IS YOUR FRIEND