# Give access to JSP file/folder only for particular IP address

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, ip

I made a CMS application using JSP and servlet. I am not using any kind of framework. The CMS has 2 parts:

1. Front end
2. Admin (Back end)

If I hosted it on `www.example.com`, for example, then all my frond end site will show for all users.

But `www.example.com/admin` must be accessible from a couple of IP addresses. Not from all the users.

I found these links:

- [link 1](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=445942)
- [link 2](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=494)
- [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381531/tomcat-restrict-access-by-ip-address)

Link 1 looks bit confusing and Link 2 looks good, but I am not using JBoss.

In the Stack Overflow link they did not mention how to use it.

Comment: It would be better if you post info about the Web Application Server you're using. Saying "I'm not using JBoss" is not enough info to help you.

Comment: Yes.. I am using `apache 6.0`...

Comment: In this case apply [Remote Adress Request Filter Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter) to solve your issue. Add in `server.xml` following: `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="192.168.5.11"/>` where `192.168.5.11` is value of your IP address. Or a regexp, for example `192\.168\.1\.\d+`.

Comment: @Andrey Kapelchik yes.. same thing i expected.. got the answer as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand from your question you use the `Apache Tomcat` as a web server. In that case use [Remote Address Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter) to restrict access by IP address. It allows comparing IP of the requesting client with regular expressions to either allow or prevent the request based on the results of the comparison.

If you use [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/) you need use class [RemoteAddrFilter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/RemoteAddrFilter.html) and define regular expressions for necessary IP in the application's configuration file `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>allow</param-name> <!-- or deny -->
      <param-value>10\.10\.1[12]\..*</param-value> <!-- regexp for your ip adress -->
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*/admin</url-pattern> <!-- the url of your admin page -->
</filter-mapping>
```

You can use hardcoded specific IP address or regular expression patterns. But in some cases regular expressions gives you a lot of flexibility in validation of addresses.

And if you use [6](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/) or [5](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/) version of Tomcat you need use class [RemoteAddrValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteAddrValve.html) and define following line in Tomcat's configuration file `server.xml`:

```
<Valve className=”org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve” allow=”10\.10\.1[12]\..*”/>
```

or

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
    deny="86.57.158.37, 213.117.195.*, 124.86.42.*" />
```

More information about [using request filter valves](http://books.google.by/books?id=bgMKmsXVbTAC&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=tomcat+Remote+Address+Filter+example&source=bl&ots=tpGJMIhsWZ&sig=-he76l1CJEGwXPhayLzvpnMvqMc&sa=X&ei=KeowUMm7J43ItAbbkYDQBg&ved=0CCoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

And interesting article about [securing the administrative web apps with Tomcat](http://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/tomcat6-securing-the-administrative-webapps/).

And by the way there's convenient  to not deny requests from `localhost` for testing. So it makes sense to add `127\.0\.0\.1` to your allowable range of IP adresses.

But don't forget that in some cases a proxy server can be used to get around the IP block. Apply also login authentication for better security.

Comment: right now i am using tomcat 6, when i tried `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" dany="123.201.198.241"/>`, its not working. Secondly how to give access only for `/admin`..?

Comment: Try change - dany="123.201.198.241" to deny="123.201.198.241"

Comment: In the example you gave above - <Valve className=”org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve” allow=”10\.10\.1[12]\..*”/> does the referenced range equate to 10.10.1.0 to 12 or is it 10.10.1 to 12 and the any number after that for the last octet?

Answer (score 5):

You can define a `WebFilter`.

An example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter(filterName = "ezSecurityAdminFilter", urlPatterns = "/admin/*")
public class EZSecurityAdminFilter implements Filter {

    private static String allowIP = "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;


        String ipAddr = req.getRemoteAddr();

        System.out.println("IP-Addr: " + ipAddr);

        if (ipAddr.equals(allowIP)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {

            res.sendRedirect("/WebApplication1/access_denied.jsp");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

All request from a other IP address then `allowIP` will be redirected.