# Have Petaho has IP restriction setting for user console?

Tags: ip-address, pentaho, restriction

I want to restrict some IP address so that so IP cannot connect to Pentaho user console (PUC), Can I do that?
If it can, how to set it or where is the setting file about IP
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho just runs on Tomcat.  So look at either Tomcat or Apache for this, e.g:

[Tomcat Restrict access by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381531/tomcat-restrict-access-by-ip-address)

(using valves)

It does have inbuilt restriction on where the Admin console can connect from, but it doesnt sound like you're talking about that.