# limit tomcat users by specific number of Ip or mac addresses concurrently

Tags: tomcat, limit

Please Help Me to limit access to my web app by specific number Ip or mac concurrent

*please take care i'm not a programmer :)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as duplicate of [Tomcat Restrict access by IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381531/tomcat-restrict-access-by-ip-address) , the other solution is to limit access on firewall level. Tomcat ussually run on 8080, 80, 8443 or 443 depending on configuration so you can allow access to those ports only from certain IP's. Please note that via firewall you will limit access to all your applications on tomcat server.

Comment: thank you for your answer
but maybe i wasn't be able to let you know what i mean

--for example :
i don't want to say only ip '192.168.1.13' to access the program

-- i want to let any three different ips to access my sever but when the fourth comming to enter the server don't allow him untill one ip from the three finishes work and log out from server then any other ip can login and work
--i think it's more like if i making empty slots and any one can use it and leave it empty again for any ip

thanks

Comment: This has to be supported by application then. Via some kind of authentication servlet filter. I do not think you are able to do this via configuration of tomcat only withou modify your application war.