# Spring - Allow only specific domain requests with out spring configuring spring security

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.10, My project track specific request from specific domain. I am using some api which notify my application, if some event occurs.

My application will receive only from specific domains which that api belongs.
Eg: https://console.developers.google.com/apis

I want to restrict my endpoints to get request from specific domains like above example.

My application don't need any security. So, i am not interested to spring security. So how i can restrict my application to accept requests only from specific domain.

Comment: @dur, I need programmatic solution. My Server is tomcat. Other applications also deployed on that.

Comment: For Tomcat see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381531/tomcat-restrict-access-by-ip-address

Comment: @dur, I want do pragmatically.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the @CrossOrigin annotation on you controller methods or on class level if you have controller level requirements.

For example if you use it as 
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000") it will only allow requests from http://localhost:9000 domain.

You can check sample usage in below url:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: You answer is wrong: First, it only works with browser (with CORS enabled), not any other HTTP client. Second: It doesn't check the remote IP address, it checks the origin of client's source code.