# How to restrict access by IP address to specific path with Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, ip-restrictions

Dears,

Can anyone help on restricting the access to a specific path on the web application by IP address?

Currently I have applied RemoteAddrValve and it perfectly works for all web application directory. Actually I need to apply this only on specific path.

It is highly appreciated if someone can help on this.

```
<Context><WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource><Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" deny="some IPs" denyStatus="404"/></Context>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict access by IP address with Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381531/how-to-restrict-access-by-ip-address-with-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the `RemoteAddrValve` is too broad for your need. The solution is to use the `RewriteValve` matching both conditions (IP + path) and for the rule, denying the traffic. Don't forget to read the [Tomcat doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/rewrite.html) to learn more on rewrites.

First, add the adequate valve in your Host definition in server.xml :

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

Supposing your host name is the default one (localhost), you need to create `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config` file with this content :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} bad.ip.addr.ess
RewriteRule ^/forbidden-path(.*)$ / [F]
```

The F flag will send a 403 Forbidden HTTP code. You can change the rule as you want, for example to redirect to a login page (flag R).

If your website is exposed on Internet, don't forget that anyone could use a proxy to hide its real IP address. If you're using a reverse-proxy in front of your Apache, you might need to configure it adequately not to loose the user's real IP of your Tomcat could only see your reverse proxy IP.